# function not working in .animation left property

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have the following code (part of a function):

```
$stock.click(function () {
    $waste.append($stock.children('.container:lt(3)').card('upturn').droppable('disable').css( "left", function(i) {return ["70px", "85px", "100px"][i];}) );
  });
```

It takes the first 3 divs (with class container) and places them next to each other. Works great!

Now I want to animate this with jquery `.animation`. I've come up with this code:

```
$waste.append($stock.children('.container:lt(3)').card('upturn').droppable('disable').css( "left", "-70px" ).animate({"left": function(i) {return ["+=70px", "+=85px", "+=100px"][i];}}, "fast") );
```

Changes I've made:

- `.css( "left", "-70px" )` put the div back on the original stock div pile so we can add an animation
- `.animate({"left": function(i) {return ["+=70px", "+=85px", "+=100px"][i];}}, "fast")` should move the first div 70px, the second 85px and the last 100px

But it aint working. Can this be done? And how?

Ps I have also tried:

```
$waste.append($stock.children('.container:lt(3):nth-child(1)').card('upturn').droppable('disable').css( "left", "-70px" ).animate({"left": "+=70px"}, "fast"));
$waste.append($stock.children('.container:lt(3):nth-child(2)').card('upturn').droppable('disable').css( "left", "-70px" ).animate({"left": "+=85px"}, "fast"));
$waste.append($stock.children('.container:lt(3):nth-child(3)').card('upturn').droppable('disable').css( "left", "-70px" ).animate({"left": "+=100px"}, "fast"));
```

Though this seems to work, it isn't bug free (the last click should contain 3 divs, but it will show and move 2 divs and after clicking the stock div again it will show and move the last remaining div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do:

```
$waste.append($stock.children('.container:lt(3)').card('upturn').droppable('disable').css( "left", "-70px" );
$waste.append($stock.children('.container:lt(3)').each(function(index, val){
    switch(index){
        case 0:
            $(this).animate({"left":'+=70px'},'fast');
            break;
        case 1:
            $(this).animate({"left":'+=85px'},'fast');
            break;
        case 2:
            $(this).animate({"left":'+=100px'},'fast');
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Had to modify the code a bit, but it worked, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it triggered an idea! ;)